# RKClient is nil

Tags: restkit

This line of code:

```
    RKClient *client = [RKClient sharedClient];
```

returns nil for `client`.

```
    RKLogConfigureByName("RestKit", RKLogLevelTrace);
```

gives:

```
I restkit:RKLog.m:33 RestKit initialized...
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure it indeed is `nil`? How do you get informed about it being `nil`?

Comment: Putting a breakpoint there and looking at it in Xcode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, this is because the method just delivers the shared client. Which is nil until you use something like this:

```
RKClient *client = [RKClient clientWithBaseURL:url];
```

==== UPDATE

As @Dan suggested, using RKObjectManager is the better way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into using RKObjectManager, instead. RKObjectManager creates an RKClient, and is the main mechanism to serialize / deserialize objects.